# pdfSharp printing with page size

Tags: pdf, printing, pdfsharp

I am using PdfSharp dll to print a pdf. This is the code that i am using. This works fine for me.

```
PdfFilePrinter.AdobeReaderPath = "C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Reader 9.0\\Reader\\AcroRd32.exe";
PdfFilePrinter printer = new PdfFilePrinter("C:\\sample.pdf", "HP LaserJet P1007");
printer.Print();
```

As always!!!! "BUT" I am not able to apply page size like A4 to the above code. So is there any way that i can implement page size to the code here.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PdfFilePrinter launches AcroRd32.exe and passes file name and printer name in the command line. I'm afraid the command line does not support selection of paper format or other advanced options.

Comment: There is and PageSizes Class in the PDF Sharp Samples. In that there is an option to set the page sizes but we can only view the pdf files. Is there any option with which we can implement printing in that??

Comment: With PDFsharp you can create PDF files with varying page sizes (every page can have a new size). That's what PageSizes is for. PDFsharp cannot print PDF files. When printing, the printing application (here Adobe Reader) must select the printer's paper size that best matches the size of the page in the PDF file. Typically there is one paper feed so you say "use A4" or "use Letter".

Comment: Thanks a lot.. the thing is that there were a lot of pdfs already created. so i was trying to print those files with Size. well i have to edit the code where the pdf is being generated so that in future cases isuues dont occur.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6900744/printing-pdfs-with-changed-default-printer-settings?lq=1