# Printing PDFs with changed default printer settings

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, printing

Google/Bing didnt bring up any solution to my following problem, hope someone can help me:

We have to print various PDF files in our C# based program. Before we can print, we have to configure the printer, e.g. setting the orientation to landscape.

I tried to change the default printer settings e.g. like this:

```
PrinterSettings settings = new PrinterSettings();
settings.PrinterName = "\\\\SomeNetworkPrinter\\";
settings.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
settings.Duplex = Duplex.Horizontal;
```

We send the PDF to the printer via PDFSharp, which basically works, but my settings are completly ignored. Isn't it possible to change the default printer settings this way? Do we have any chance to change the settings and print our PDF-files?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: See here: [pdfSharp printing with page size](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6277554) Looks like you'll have to alter the PDF file its self.

Comment: Perhaps can offer more help if you can post the code you use to invoke PDFSharp

Comment: Thanks George! Can we set settings like Duplex, PageSize and Orientation in the PDF directly?

Comment: Well, you can set settings like Duplex, Orientation etc. directly in the PDF (e.g. via iText), but our printers ignored those settings completly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question ...

After 3 days of trial and error I dont think there is any chance to configure the printer via .NET and print PDFs afterwards. You cant use the System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument class in combination with PDFs, but using PrintDocument seems to be a prerequisit to change the printer settings.

My solution to configure the printer was inspired by this post on codeplex: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/NET_Printer_Library.aspx

To finally print the pdf I send it via commandline parameters to Adobe Reader.

Comment: Hi there Can you please post the code for the combination of passing commandline parameters and then using this http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/NET_Printer_Library.aspx to set printer settings as I can't combine these 2 together THanks

Comment: Can you post the code that you used?  The codeproject code is not so great.

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think that's going to work.

You're creating a local [`PrinterSettings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printersettings%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) object which can be used to configure a [`PrintDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/68eybb19%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) which in turn can be sent to the printer using [`PrintDocument.Print()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.print%28v=VS.71%29.aspx).

If you're calling out to PDFSharp to orchestrate the printing, it's going to use whatever printer settings it defaults to, unless you're somehow passing your [`PrinterSettings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printersettings%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) to PDFSharp via the API?

If you can post the code you use to invoke PDFSharp, it would be of help in figuring out how to do this.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I invoke PDFSharp like in this quesion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6277554/pdfsharp-printing-with-page-size

Can we use PrintDocument to print our PDF file or do we have to use Acrobat Reader/GhostScript, ...?