# c# printing 2 pages per sheet how programmatically?

Tags: c#, pdf, printing, adobe

After 2-3 weeks of trying to programmatically get this to work without trying to use 3rd party vendors, I'm still struggling to try to accomplish the task of outputting 2 pdf pages on the same page, landscape on a standard sheet of paper.  What I'm at least able to do is merge 2 different pdf outputs into one file stream for printing purposes, but when I try to print, the pages appear separately.  In essence, I'm trying to replicate the following print dialog automatically but without the print dialog:
[image]

Here's the c# code I've done so far in attempting this with my final output:

```
        PrinterSettings settings = new PrinterSettings();
        string printerName = settings.PrinterName;

        printDlg.PrintTicket.PagesPerSheet = 2;
        string rwPrinter = printerName;

        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        process.StartInfo.FileName = printFile;
        if (rwPrinter.Length > 0)
        {
            process.StartInfo.Verb = "printto";
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = "\"" + rwPrinter + "\"";
        }
        else
        {
            process.StartInfo.Verb = "print";
        }

        try
        {
            process.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        process.WaitForInputIdle();
```

I'm seeking any possible solutions without necessarily invoking 3rd party software may with the exception of an Adobe SDK in order to get this idea done, Please advise, thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Printing PDFs with changed default printer settings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6900744/printing-pdfs-with-changed-default-printer-settings)

Comment: Hmmm, commandline parameters to Adobe Reader?  I'll try that direction, sooner I can get an acceptable solution this the better.

Comment: Update, while using adobe commands looks encouraging, what I need is a way to indicate pages per sheet to be set to 2.